# Random Output Generator - Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

Anyone know how I could build a random output generator in Wordpress? Thinking of a button one could click to automatically generate random results

Comment: Numbers? string? password ... ? What output should it be?

Comment: int rand ( int $min , int $max )